# some fields not getting captured from VF page

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have a VF page which has a popup  to accept a few fields.

When I run the page and fill in the fields, I can see that only some field values are getting captured, others are returining as null.  I cross checked the field names, they are the same. Any ideas why this could happen?

```
<apex:outputPanel id="tstpopup1">
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBackground" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}"/>
            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="custPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}">
            <apex:pageblock >
                <apex:pageblocksection >
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                    <apex:outputlabel value="Project: " />
                    <apex:inputfield id="proj" value="{!AC.Project__c}" />
                    </apex:pageblocksectionitem><p/>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                    <apex:outputlabel value="Start Date: " />
                    <apex:inputfield id="sd" value="{!AC.Start_Date__c}" />
                    </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                    <apex:outputlabel value="End Date: " />
                    <apex:inputfield id="ed" value="{!AC.End_Date__c}" />
                    </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                    <apex:outputlabel value="C85 Project Lead: " />
                    <apex:inputfield id="pl" value="{!AC.C85_Project_Lead__c}" />
                    </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                    <apex:outputlabel value="Daily Charge Rate of Consultant: " />
                    <apex:inputfield id="charge" value="{!AC.Daily_Charge_Rate_of_Consultant__c}" />
                    </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                    <apex:outputlabel value="Project Role Title: " />
                    <apex:inputfield id="role" value="{!AC.Project_Role_Title__c}" />
                    </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                    <apex:outputlabel value="Overtime Allowed: " />
                    <apex:inputfield id="overtime" value="{!AC.overtime_allowed__c}" />
                    </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                    </apex:pageblocksection>
                    <apex:commandbutton value="Assign to a New Project" action="{!assign}"   />
                    <apex:commandbutton value="Cancel" action="{!closePopup}" immediate="true" /><br/><br/><br/>
                    </apex:pageblock>
            </apex:outputPanel>
```

Class has this

```
    public Assigned_Consultant__c AC{
        get{
            if (AC == null) AC = new Assigned_Consultant__c();
            return AC;
        }
        set; 
    }


public PageReference assign()
{ 
system.debug('Role title ...........................' + AC.Project_Role_Title__c); // this is returning null
            system.debug('Day charge ...........................' + AC.Daily_Charge_Rate_of_Consultant__c); this has value filled
system.debug('overtime_allowed__c ...........................' + AC.overtime_allowed__c);  // this is returning null


         // Project_Role_Title__c
            displayPopup = false;  
            system.debug('inside assign...........................3');
            system.debug('AC.................' + AC);   

  }
```

Comment: I'm guessing, but could it be permissions in the profile?

Comment: Maybe some input fields doesn't correspond to a types of object's fields? Or they may be read-only.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial is a little dated, but I think it might help explain some of the issues associated with what you're trying to do: [Tutorial: Modal Dialogs in Visualforce](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Tutorial%3a_Modal_Dialogs_in_Visualforce_using_the_Yahoo!_User_Interface_Library).

> "Building a link or button to popup a new Visualforce page is actually
>   quite simple, and getting this popup to be above the current page is
>   also quite easy. The problem occurs when you would like to collect
>   information in the popup and pass that information back to the page
>   that launched the popup."